# Move to bottom of Textbox

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a way to programmatically jump to the bottom (last line) of a TextBox shape? If not, can the same be achieved using a Plain Text Content Control?

The following hasn't worked for me:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes("Text Box 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Select
Selection.EndKey WdUnits.wdStory, False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using selections (I wouldn't), you could use:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes("Text Box 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Last.Select
```

Do note that, just like anywhere else in a document, the last line in an empty range is at the top of that range.

Comment: That answers the question I had asked, so I'll award it. However I later figured out that *standard* TextBoxes do not support scrollbars (which I need), so I had to switch to OLE TextBox.

Comment: Also that VBA doesn't show `Last` as a member of `Characters`, so I had to use `Characters.Length` as index to access last character.

Comment: "Also that VBA doesn't show Last as a member of Characters" - It *does* for a standard textbox such as your first post described...